# First call socket.recv(size) takes almost 0.5s

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I am trying to get data from my server that I want to visualize in Bokeh. Therefore I call my getData() function periodically. The function works, but it is extremely slow. To call this function it needs about 0.4s to get a data point.

I checked where the bottleneck of the function is and 99.99% of the time is due to the first call of the function sock.revc(2048) and I have no idea why this could happen. I would be very grateful if someone has an idea why this could happen.

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1)
sock.connect(("127.0.0.0", 123456))

start = time.time()
sock.recv(2048) #about 0.4 s
stop = time.time()

start2 = time.time()
sock.recv(2048) #about 2E-6 s
stop2 = time.time()
'''
some Code which preprocess my sample data
'''
print(stop - start)
print(stop2 - start2)

sock.close()
```

Comment: ``socket.recv(n)`` returns *up to* ``n`` bytes. Did you actually check whether both calls ``sock.recv(2048)`` did return the same amount of content? Does the server send data immediately?

Comment: Yes both calls return the same amount of bytes. I also checked the function calls with 1 byte and the time-values are almost the same. The Server sends raw data the whole time.